# Props became undefined during props

Tags: vuejs2

this is a part of my vue project with webpack.

```
<template>
<div>
      <p>notes is: {{notes}}</p>
      <p>{{notes[0]}}</p>
      <Card :note="notes[0]"/>
      <Card :note="this.notes[0]"/>
</div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  import Card from './Card/Card.vue'
  export default {
    name: 'Card',
    props: ["notes"],
    components: {
      Card
    }
  }
</script>
```

`notes` is props value from father component.

this is the result after compiler to the webpage.

As you can see `notes` is an array and shows in the p elements.

But when I try to props it to the child component, browser throw error: 
Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

What makes `notes` to be undefined?

[image]

Comment: And where from do u get notes? Because your are accessing them before they get populated, so a error.

Answer (score 0):

'notes' is not accessible when your child component is mounted. Hence, vue isn't able to access the desired value during render.

Just add a reference guard in your template wherever you are passing it as a prop to the child component

```
<Card :note="notes && notes[0]"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

props are not available till components is rendered , you can use v-if and you will get no error